# using autogen.sh with ExternalProject_Add

Tags: linux, cmake, configure, external-project, autogen

I try to set ExternalProject_Add in CMakeLists.txt,

for doing this I found this question :

[What is the correct usage of CMake EXTERNALPROJECT_ADD with a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440163/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-cmake-externalproject-add-with-a-git-repository)

But I have an issue, I can't call `CONFIGURE_COMMAND configure`, because I have to call `./autogen.sh` to generate `configure.ac`.
I don't find how to make cmake runing `./autogen.sh`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) about `ExternalProject`:

> Any builtin step that specifies a `<step>_COMMAND cmd...` or custom step that specifies a `COMMAND cmd...` may specify additional command lines using the form `COMMAND cmd...`. At build time the commands will be executed in order and aborted if any one fails.

You may specify several commands for being executed at *configure* step of external project:

```
ExternalProject_Add(<some_project>
   ...
   CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./autogen.sh COMMAND ./configure
)
```